# Drone Chord Android App

Tags: android, music-production

Do you know any Android App where... there would be two buttons/select boxes: "key" and "chord" where I could do something like:

- Key: C
- Chord: 7M

Hit a "play" button and it would just... play it. Without tempo, without rhythm, without sound sample files nor nothing... Just a single, sustained chord played indefinitely till the heat-sink death of the universe.

I just spent the last 3 hours installing and testing apps and I find unbelievable that something as simple as this just plain doesn't exists.

Comment: While I don't really have any software recommendations, **let me suggest finding software that can play sine waves, then play 4 different ones at the correct frequencies.** I know for a fact it's easy to find apps to play sine waves *(sine wave generator, for example).*

Answer (score 0):

Try Piano Companion android app, select Chords Dictionary sub menu.

If you want the sound in different instrument try Music Tool Kit android app and define your key and chord in the staff and hit play button, Select different instrument using edit icon in the left side of staff line.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot and say whether the app is free or not? Thanks! :-)